# AlarmManager сдвигает время на 12 часов

Tags: android, android-alarm-manager

Привет!
Уже несколько дней бьюсь над проблемой - в приложении нужно сделать показ уведомления с определенным интервалом.
Соответственно пользую AlarmManager. Запускаю единичный alarm, а при обработке планирую следующий. Все стандартно. Но. Через несколько установок alarm время ставится +12 часов. Т.е. задаю к примеру 09:00 - а в логе вижу 21:00.

Вот код функции планирования alarm-а:

```
    private void rescheduleNotification(Context context) {
    long nextNotifTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // Schedule next notification in 15 minutes
    nextNotifTime += 15 * 60 * 1000;

    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(nextNotifTime);
    // It's an old version with the same result
    //calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
    this.logEvent("      Next notification time is: " + sdf.format(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, WordsBcReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        manager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextNotifTime, pendingIntent);
    } else {
        manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextNotifTime, pendingIntent);
    }
    this.logEvent("   Set next notification time: " + sdf.format(nextNotifTime));
}
```

Вот, что вижу в своем логе:

```
29/12/17 11:30:36:    Next notification time is: 29/12/17 12:00:36
29/12/17 11:30:36:    Set next notification time: 29/12/17 12:00:36
```

И вот, что пишет ***adb shell dumpsys alarm***:

```
type=0 whenElapsed=+11h34m13s906ms when=2017-12-30 00:00:36
```

Всю голову уже сломал, временно отказался от Calendar - просто получаю текущее время и тупо прибавляю нужное кол-во мс - но не помогает. Установка времени относительно момента старта ОС - аналогично. То ставит нормальное время, то +12 час.
Может кто сталкивался с таким?

Comment: Выяснил, что сдвиг происходит при следующем после отключения шнура питания вызове rescheduleNotification.
Проявляется на Honor 7, а на HTC One - нет...

Answer (score 0):

Дело точно не в календаре. Скорее всего дело в вашем способе обновления временного интервала, который накладывается на особенности работы **AlarmManager**. Например он может запуститься и обновить время запуска при перезапуске приложения.

Для корректной работы, временные интервалы правильнее задавать внутри **AlarmManager** через `.setRepeating()`. Примерно так.

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
    notifyTime.getTimeInMillis(),
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES,
    pendingIntent);
```

Comment: с setRepeating аналогичные проблемы... Да и потом использовать setRepeating не хотелось, т.к. дальше хотел исключать определенные периоды (например ночь)

Comment: @Romaann, вы можете настроить **AlarmManager** на срабатывание с определенным интервалом, а условия показа уведомлений, в том числе и допустимое время показа, проверять внутри ресивера.